# Monte Carlo Confidence about estimating a distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, simulation, density-function, monte-carlo

I am trying to estimate the distribution of a discrete random variable $X$ with a finite set of outcomes $w_1, w_2,...w_m$. I have access to a simulator $G$, that outputs a realization $x_i$ of the variable in the $i^\text{th}$ iteration of simulation.

My estimates of the distribution, after $n$ runs of the simulation is given by

$P(X=w_j) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}(x_i = w_j)}{n} \,\, \, \forall j \in \{1..m\}$

My question is regarding confidence in the estimates of $P(X=w_j)$. What is the standard way to conclude, for a given confidence measure $\alpha$ and interval $\gamma$ , that there is an $\alpha$ chance that my estimates are within $\gamma$ of my current estimates. More intuitively, how do I know for a given confidence measure $\alpha$, I have run enough simulations?